# ms outlook for job chain notification

Tags: excel, vba, notifications, outlook

I need an advice how to approach the problem from the title.
Is it possible to use MS Outlook for job chain notifications.

Here is the scenario:
I have a project with several project members defined at the beginning of the project. The project manager defines the team members and specifics of the project and launches the project by sending the first job to the first team member. As the first team member completes the first job they tick the completion box or click a button the next team member gets the job notification and so on. Each time the project manager is also notified about the progress.

I don't want the team members entering the next recipients and changing the mail subject manually.

My two questions:
1. Can this be achieved?
2. If it can be done, which approach to take, just by designing a template or programing with VBA?

Additional note: All the data for the email message is stored in the excel project book so ideally I'd get that data from the excel.

regards,
seba

Comment: If all the data for the email message is in your excel book, you could just send the emails directly from excel. You could build a userform that allows the user to check off when they're done and it'll send the notification emails.

Comment: Do you mean a userform in Excel or in Outlook? I'd like to avoid having a shared book to manage such notifications (had this once before), but rather move this notifications to Outlook. The trigger can of course be in the Excel.

Comment: You could certainly create the userform in Outlook and call it from Excel. You would just need to make sure that each person has the correct userform saved in Outlook on their computer.

Comment: I've created additional project management modules in excel which hold the data required. Then I use excel to send mail notifications. First, when the job chain is triggered and then conditionally when certain cell has a specific value in each job chain module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can automate Outlook from another applications. See [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) for more information (a sample code is included).